# Fastest way to add -movflags +faststart to an MP4 using FFMPEG, leaving everything else as-is

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I want to add `-movflags +faststart` to an mp4 file. Basically that is all I want to do, nothing else should be changed. I am using ffmpeg.

What's the fastest way to do this? Do I have to re-encode the whole video? Or is there a better/easier way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As simple as:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

Or if you can compile FFmpeg from source, make the tool qt-faststart in the tools/ directory and run it:

```
qt-faststart in.mp4 out.mp4
```

You can also use mp4box, which lets you move the MOOV atom to the start via this command:

```
mp4box -inter 0 in.mp4 -out out.mp4
```

Or if you want to fully [optimize for streaming by also interleaving the audio/video data](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/2011/02/02/mp4box-fragmentation-segmentation-splitting-and-interleaving/) so that the file can be easily streamed in realtime:

```
mp4box -inter 500 in.mp4 -out out.mp4
```

Comment: You may want to add `-map_metadata 0` too in order to preserve any metadata

Comment: Is there any way to "fully optimize" with ffmpeg instead of mp4box? I would be doing a transcode with ffmpeg, so it would be nice not to run a separate command.

Comment: @Gyan I'm sorry, I meant is there also a way to **interleave** with ffmpeg like with mp4box. Or, are you saying `faststart` will interleave the results? Not finding anything on Google

Comment: The MP4 muxer in ffmpeg does not support custom interleaving delta. faststart only relates to where the metadata is placed.

Comment: @Gyan just seeing your reply now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The ffmpeg command above (with either "+faststart" or just "faststart") gives me "moov atom not found" (the same error I'm trying to fix) I'm running on an .m4v file.

Comment: Is there a way to not do it under a new file and add it to the same header of the main file without reading the entire data of the file, so that we can reach the goal faster?