# How can I edit the page source to preload the next videos in a series?

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a project where I am to watch a video for specific information and select a choice then click submit, then the next video is loaded. The loading between videos tends to be upwards of 5 seconds and I would like to have the videos preloaded.

How can I edit the source code of the page to preload the next videos before clicking submit?

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6q6g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the preload attribute in the HTML5 video tag.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

See the note also about it being a hint - most browsers currently follow it:

> Note:
>   The autoplay attribute has precedence over preload. If autoplay is specified, the browser would obviously need to start downloading the video for playback.
>   The specification does not force the browser to follow the value of this attribute; it is a mere hint.

The snippet below shows an example. Note that it is important you videos are optimised for streaming also if they are mp4 with the header at the start - see YouTube recommendations:https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en and the info with the Quickstart tool here: https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart

You can use this tool, ffmpeg, Handbrake etc to make this optimisation - for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50914703/334402

```js
var vid1 = document.getElementById("MyVid1");
var vid2 = document.getElementById("MyVid2");

vid1.onloadeddata = function() {
    vid1.currentTime = 882; //Go to end of video for this illustration
    vid1.play()
};

vid2.onloadeddata = function() {
    vid2.pause()
};

nextVideoStart = function() {
    vid2.play()
};
```

```html
<video id="MyVid1" width="320" height="176" controls preload="auto">
  <source   src="http://peach.themazzone.com/durian/movies/sintel-1024-surround.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support this video format
</video>

<video id="MyVid2" width="320" height="176" controls preload="auto">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support this video format
</video>

<p></p>

<button onclick="nextVideoStart()">Click for next video</button>
```